# Link_to redirecting wrong

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a strange problem with link_to, this is what happens:
When I click in this link_to:

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %></li>
```

It redirect to sessions/new, but I want to go to users/new
I think my routes.rb is wrong but I don't see anything wrong
This is my route.rb:

```
get "sessions/new"
get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up" 
get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"  
get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
root :to => "sessions#new"  
resources :users  

resources :sessions

resources :orchestras

resources :conductors

resources :instruments

resources :integrants
```

If someone can help, Thanks.

**Update**

@ChrisPeters said to me see if there is a before_action redirecting me to my sessions/new
I verify and I found a before_filter:

```
before_filter :verifyUser, :only => [:orchestras, :conductors, :instruments, :integrants, :users]
```

Because this I'm redirecting to wrong page, I change my users_controller to skip this:

```
  skip_before_action :verifyUser, only: [:new]
```

And now it's working.
Thanks @ChrisPeters.

Comment: Does `users#new` get intercepted by a `before_action` that checks if the user is logged in and redirects the user to the login page?

Comment: @ChrisPeters yes there is a before_action, but in my users_controller I do this:
   skip_before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:new]

Comment: @ChrisPeters Sorry I forgot to see there is another before_action , this before_action that redirect me to the sessions/new, I said to skip_before_action in my users_controller and now its working, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if there is a `before_action` intercepting the request and redirecting the user to `sessions#new`.

As you said in your update, it looks like you had missed one:

```
before_filter :verifyUser, :only => [:orchestras, :conductors, :instruments, :integrants, :users]
```

And you were able to resolve by calling `skip_before_action`:

```
skip_before_action :verifyUser, only: [:new]
```

One small pointer would be to rename your filter method to `verify_user` because `snake_case` is the conventional Ruby way to name your methods.